# What approach to take to parameterise a C2, monotonic, piecewise polynomial?

Tags: interpolation, monotone-functions, equicontinuity

I have a set of points `(x, y)` and need to monotonically interpolate between them. The resulting polynomial needs to be C2 continuous. Could you point me in the right direction? From what I've seen I cannot use cubic splines since they would have either monotonicity or C2-continuity, but not both. Is it necessary to go for quartic polynomials then?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "monotonically interpolate".

Comment: I mean that the slope at any point between 2 knots needs to have the same sign (i.e. no local max/min between 2 knots)

Comment: So if two consecutive knots have the same $y$ value, the polynomial must be constant on this interval?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, just a constant line between the knots

Comment: So e.g. if your set of points was $(0,0), (1,0), (2,1), (3,1)$ the polynomial $p(x)$ in the interval $[1,2]$ would need $p(1) = 0$, $p'(1) = 0$, $p''(1) = 0$, $p(2) = 1$, $p'(2) = 0$, $p''(2) = 0$.
That requires a polynomial of degree at least $5$.